# Excel Web - Possible to create Workbook Links using INDIRECT function?

Tags: excel, excel-online, excel-web-query

I have seen questions on using INDIRECT to reference closed workbooks, but my case in excel web, where source workbook and destination workbook are both excel online/web and I would like to reference destination in source via workbook links.

Using workbook links as mentioned [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/workbook-link-support-coming-to-excel-for-the-web/ba-p/1590314) works, but I am wondering if this link can be created dynamically using INDIRECT function since I need to form the destination link dynamically based on other values in the source sheet.

I believe unless the link is direct, its not possible to use indirect functions as workbook links, especially in Excel web? Please confirm or correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible, `INDIRECT()` doesnt works on web. At least till now, its not possible, until and unless there are new updates from `MS`, may be with `Offie Scripts` however no idea

Comment: Thanks @Mayukh. INDIRECT as a function works in Excel Online, at least with simple cases. It seems that using INDIRECT doesn't result in forming proper "Workbook links", they aren't recognized.